# Create semantic url to redirect to section on frontpage

Tags: url-rewrite

I would like to create a semantic URL for my print material that should look something like mysite.com/newsletter.
However I do not have a specific page for my newsletter at the moment. Therefore I would like to redirect to a specific section on the frontpage. Is this possible

Answer (score 1):

Either you just create a page called /newsletter and leave it empty and then set a URL rewrite from /newsletter to /thepageyouwant

Or you just set a URL rewrite from /newsletter to /thepageyouwant in the Magento URL rewrite management

So Requested Path is "newsletter" and target path the URL you want to link to.

Can be found in `Catalog--> URL Rewrite Management`

[image]